# Caching a model while loading

Tags: caching, tensorflow.js

I currently load a model in `tfjs` with the following code. I'm attempting to optimize the model by caching the files closer to where the model is called from using CloudFlare's Cache API. Is there a way for me to intercept the fetch call in the load operation to cache the model data and load data fetched from a cache into the model?

**Current Code:**

```js
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel("model_url_from_gcp")
```

**Trying to achieve:**

```js
// Will load data from cache if data is cached, else will fetch from URL and cache
const load_data = cache.get("model_url_from_gcp")

// Will load cached data into Model instead of using a URL 
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(load_data)
```

Is there also a way to achieve the same for GraphModels from TFHub?

```
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel("some_tfhub_url", { fromTFHub: true })
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use something like localstorage or indexdb on the browser itself? Honestly though as long as the correct headers are set by GCP for the model etc the browser automatically caches files if the headers state to so it does this for free typically.  If you want things to work offline though, then look into PWA examples.

Comment: No, I'm trying to cache on a CDN's caching API and load the response of a get call into tf.loadLayersModel(). That way I can abstract away which server the data is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

For using LocalStorage or IndexDB for TensorFlow.js please see this documentation:

IndexDB: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load#indexeddb_browser_only

LocalStorage: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load#local_storage_browser_only